# Merge data in single row in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

my table like this data. i want  to change below output format in oracle.

```
ID  NAME    SALARY  CITY
1   Raman   null    null
1   null    1000    null
1   null    null    Chennai
2   null    1500    null
2   null    null    Mumbai
2   Manoj   null    null
3   Bala    2000    null
3   null    null    Trichy
```

Expected Output
ID  NAME    SALARY  CITY

```
1   Raman   1000    Chennai
2   Manoj   1500    Mumbai
3   Bala    2000    Trichy
```

Comment: Use group by with max

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Group By` clause with the `MAX` aggregate function.

```
SELECT ID,max(NAME) AS Name,max(SALARY) AS Salary,max(CITY) AS City
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```